# Quotation App - Rails Active Record Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm hoping someone can help me with this as I've been trying to think of the best way to do it for a couple of days.

I'm building a quotation app that has Stores, Brands, Products and Discounts.

Each store can have many brands and each brand will have a discount amount depending on the store.

So for example I might have store_1 which has 10% off brand_1 and store_2 which has 20% off brand_1.

How would I best setup the relationships between these models so that I can easily get the discount amount for a brand via a product but filtered by store?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to set this up is as follows:

```
Store -> has_many :discounts
Store -> has_many :brands, through: :discounts

Brand -> has_many :discounts
Brand -> has_many :stores, through: :discounts

Discount -> belongs_to :brand
Discount -> belongs_to :store
```

This will give you the ability to make calls like:

```
store.brands
store.discounts

brand.stores
brand.discounts

discount.store
discount.brand
```

If you want to find how much of a discount you're giving at a certain store for a certain brand you can do this:

```
brand.stores.find_by(name: 'Store Name').discounts
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it's very much appreciated. Can I just ask, if I wanted to get the discount for a brand via a product and filtered by store, how would I do that? would it be like this - `product.brand.discounts.find_by(store_id: 2)` - or is there a better way?

Comment: It depends on how you setup your product association.

Comment: So I have them setup like so:

`Brand -> has_many :products`
`Product -> belongs_to :brand`